# Problema ao fazer script python solicitar permissão de administrador

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Uso Python 3.5 no Windows 8 e um simples script apresentou problema: quero copiar um arquivo da minha área de trabalho para a pasta C:\Windows. Primeiro tentei isso:

```
from shutil import copy

path1='C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\registro.py'
path2='C:\\Windows\\oi.txt'
copy(path1,path2)
```

Entretanto, dava erro de permissão. Então acrescentei ao script um trecho que faz com o que o script solicite permissão de administrador quando executado:

```
from shutil import copy
import sys,os,win32com.shell.shell

if sys.argv[-1]!='asadmin':
    script=os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params=' '.join([script]+sys.argv[1:]+['asadmin'])
    win32com.shell.shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas',lpFile=sys.executable,lpParameters=params)

path1='C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\registro.py'
path2='C:\\Windows\\oi.txt'
copy(path1,path2)
```

Ao executar tal script, realmente aparece a janela de permissão de administrador, porém, mesmo dando a permissão, o erro persistiu. Então eu tentei executar linha a linha no shell do Python executado como administrador (clicando com o botão direito) e deu certo. Porque não deu certo quando fiz a solicitação pelo próprio script? Há outra maneira de fazer essa solicitação pelo script?

Comment: Você já tentou copiar para a própria área de trabalho ou alguma pasta de usuário pra ver se dá o mesmo problema?

Comment: Já tentei, e não dá problema nenhum. @leonardopessoa